# Changing Culture on Drop Down Selection

Tags: asp.net-mvc, localization, globalization

I have created an application where I require is to change the culture in the drop down selection.

This is my action method code.

```
 public ActionResult SetCulture(string lang)
        {
            if (lang == "en")
                return RedirectToAction("Index");

            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(lang.Trim()); //.TextInfo.IsRightToLeft;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(lang.Trim());

            List<Agent> lstMainAgent = new List<Agent>();
            List<Agent> lstAgent = db.Agents.ToList();

            for (int i = 0; i < lstAgent.Count(); i++)
            {
                lstAgent[i].AddressCity = Resources.Resource.AddressCity;
                lstAgent[i].AddressCountry = Resources.Resource.AddressCountry;
                lstAgent[i].AddressPostcode =Resources.Resource.AddressPostcode;
                lstAgent[i].AddressStreet = Resources.Resource.AddressStreet;
                lstAgent[i].Name = Resources.Resource.Name;
                lstAgent[i].PhoneNumber = Resources.Resource.PhoneNumber;

                lstMainAgent.Add(lstAgent[i]);
            }
            return View("Index", lstMainAgent);

        }
```

This seems to be working but I have dynamic values list whose values are not added in the resource file and I am getting blank properties values in the view. I need to print all the values in the view. How can I achieve this?

**Thanks in Advance**

Comment: I am not quite understanding what you wanted to do within the for loop. Can you elaborate on that ?

Comment: i am not sure if my code is correct. Using for loop I want to pass resource values to the view in the list? Is it correct?

Comment: You can access the resource in the view. You don't need this for loop. Access like this `@Resources.Resource.AddressCountry`

Answer (score 1):

If it isn´t in the resource file it will be blank. You could, however have a default resource file and specialized ones. If it has value you fill with the specialized if not the default.

```
public ActionResult SetCulture(string culture)
{
    try
    {
         // set a default value
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(culture))
        {
            culture = "en-US";
        }

        // set the culture with the chosen name
        var cultureSet = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(culture);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture =cultureSet;
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = cultureSet;

        // set a cookie for future reference
        HttpCookie cookie = new HttpCookie("culture")
        {
            Expires = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(3),
            Value = culture
        };
        HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Add(cookie);

        List<Agent> lstAgent = db.Agents.ToList();

        foreach (Agent item in lstAgent)
        {
            item.AddressCity = Resources.Resource.AddressCity;
            item.AddressCountry = Resources.Resource.AddressCountry;
            item.AddressPostcode = Resources.Resource.AddressPostcode;
            item.AddressStreet = Resources.Resource.AddressStreet;
            item.Name = Resources.Resource.Name;
            item.PhoneNumber = Resources.Resource.PhoneNumber;
        }

        return View("Index", lstAgent);

    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        // if something happens set the culture automatically
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("auto");
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo("auto");
    }

    return View("Index");
}
```